# Where can i find and download Material Design icons for my Android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-icons

I want to use these beautiful material icons, that I can see in apps by google, so where can I find and download it?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can find all material icons by google [here](https://www.google.com/design/icons/). You are welcome to download it.
2. Also you can download all icons from [GitHub repository](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons)
3. And there is an open-source [plugin](https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin) for AndroidStudio, that makes easy to choose and add material icons to yours project - just `rightClick->new->addIcon`

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of websites that provide free material icons

http://www.materialui.co/icons

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons

https://www.google.com/design/icons/

http://www.materialup.com/tools/icons

https://materialdesignicons.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can try any of these links

- https://icons8.com/android-icons/
- https://www.google.com/design/icons/
- http://www.flaticon.com/packs/material-design

All are free for download. Enjoy